# ionic: change function on <input> is not called

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to change the value in home.html from one of my js files, once it is changed I wanted it to call the function in home.ts but it is not calling

in home.html

```
<input id="scoreboardus" (ionchange)='alertscore()' class="hello" type='hidden' value="" >
```

in one of my js files in assets/js, I am giving input value

```
$('#scoreboardus').val(somevalue);
```

and in home.ts file

```
alertscore(){
    alert('called');
}
```

But the alert is not called

I tried (change) as well as (input)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below snippet helps you.

```js
function alertscore(){
    alert('called');
}

$('#scoreboardus').val('works').trigger('onchange');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="scoreboardus" onchange='alertscore()' class="hello" type='hidden' value="" >
```

Comment: I get this error: Runtime Error
alertscore is not defined but I have it in my home.ts file

Comment: home.ts is your js file?